# erdos.renyi.game input parameters issues

Tags: igraph

According to the help file

http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/igraph/docs/erdos.renyi.game

the erdos.renyi.game function is supposed to accept n=The number of vertices in the graph and m=  the number of edges in the graph as input parameters.

The dataset I am working with has 6 vertices and 25 edges, so when i try

```
 g = erdos.renyi.game(6,25)
```

I get an error

```
 Error in .Call("R_igraph_erdos_renyi_game", as.numeric(n), as.numeric(type1),  : 
 At games.c:569 : Invalid probability given, Invalid value
```

Not sure where I am going wrong, appreciate any advise on this topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use <strike>`erdos.renyi.game(n=6, m=25)`</strike> `erdos.renyi.game(6, 12, type="gnm")` and it will work. You have to define explicitly that the second parameter is for the value of `m` and not `p`.

Comment: Actually you need `erdos.renyi.game(6, 25, type = "gnm")`.

Comment: @Tamás I tried your suggestion i got an error                       > g <- erdos.renyi.game(n=6, m=25)
Error in as.numeric(p.or.m) : 'p.or.m' is missing

Comment: @GaborCsardi I tried your approach and I got an error                    Error in .Call("R_igraph_erdos_renyi_game", as.numeric(n), as.numeric(type1),  : 
  At games.c:681 : Invalid number (too large) of edges, Invalid value

Comment: Yeah, my numbers are wrong, you can't have 25 edges in a graph with 6 vertices. Just supply proper numbers.

Comment: @Tamás: still not good, there is no argument named `m`. Just say `erdos.renyi.game(6, 12, type="gnm")`. The API is stupid, I agree, already changed it in the development version of igraph....

Comment: @GaborCsardi , i have a graph with 6 nodes and 25 edges , i dont think there is anything wrong with this, one work arround is create a matrix with 25 nodes and 25 edges, pad the unrelated (dummny) nodes and edges with 0s....this will solve the problem.

Comment: @TyroneWilliams: you were creating an undirected graph, without multiple and loop edges. Such a graph with 6 vertices can have at most 6*5/2 = 15 edges. If you want a directed graph, then specify `directed=TRUE`.

Answer (score 0):

```
erdos.renyi.game(n, p.or.m, type=c("gnp", "gnm"),
                 directed = FALSE, loops = FALSE, ...)
```

n

```
The number of vertices in the graph.
```

p.or.m

```
Either the probability for drawing an edge between two arbitrary vertices (G(n,p) graph), or the number of edges in the graph (for G(n,m) graphs).
```

type

```
The type of the random graph to create, either gnp (G(n,p) graph) or gnm (G(n,m) graph).
```

directed

```
Logical, whether the graph will be directed, defaults to FALSE.
```

loops

```
Logical, whether to add loop edges, defaults to FALSE.
```

...
    Additional arguments, ignored.

**Details**

In G(n,p) graphs, the graph has ‘n’ vertices and for each edge the probability that it is present in the graph is ‘p’.

In G(n,m) graphs, the graph has ‘n’ vertices and ‘m’ edges, and the ‘m’ edges are chosen uniformly randomly from the set of all possible edges. This set includes loop edges as well if the loops parameter is TRUE. random.graph.game is an alias to this function.

**Example:**

```
g <- erdos.renyi.game(1000, 1/1000)
degree.distribution(g)
```

Comment: I didnt catch your point ? you are saying the same thing I am saying...I know all this , in the example you mentioned erdos.renyi.game(1000, 1/1000), 1/1000 is the p , I want to try this with m =25 and it is not working.